# SwiftUI - position at top leading this view at `x` and `y`

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swiftui, figma

Goal:
Match SwiftUI position coordinates with Figma.

Context:
On Figma, the anchor is at the top leading of the layer.
On SwiftUI, the anchor is at the center of the layer, as the documentation mentions:

```
/// - Returns: A view that fixes the center of this view at `x` and `y`.
@inlinable public func position(x: CGFloat = 0, y: CGFloat = 0) -> some View
```

So when both SwiftUI and Figma are set to x:0 and y:0 positions, they don't match.

Question: how can I set the anchor in SwiftUI to be at the top leading corner?

[image]

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
 
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Circle()
            .frame(width: 132.0, height: 132.0)
            .position(x: 0, y: 0)
            
        }
        .frame(width: 731, height: 418)
        .background(.blue)

    
    }

    

}
```

Comment: Add half the width and half the height to x and y

Comment: no idea how to do this. mind giving a hand? : )

Comment: For a shape, you could barcode like    .position(x: 0 + 66, y: 0 + 66). But for an editable text, how do you fetch the size dynamically for ex?

Comment: SwiftUI is meant to be adaptable, the more hardcoded values you put in the harder you will have to work to overcome the issues. As for your latest question there are many questions in SO about getting the size of the view if you want to pursue this path, in iOS 16 there is `Layout` but I suggest you scrap the idea of hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

Centering the circle at (0, 0) will make go out of bounds because of the radius. You must do one of the following:

1. Using `HStack` & `VStack`:

```
ZStack {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 132.0, height: 132.0)
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}.frame(width: 731, height: 418)
.background(.blue)
```

2. Center the circle at (x + radius, y + radius):

```
ZStack {
    HStack {
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 132.0, height: 132.0)
    }
        .position(x: 66, y: 66)
    
}
.frame(width: 731, height: 418)
.background(.blue)
```

Comment: thanks! but the question is about having an anchor position on top leading and not positioning the circle itself,

Comment: In Figma you're not setting the center of the circle at (0,0), you're setting the min x & y to (0, 0)

Comment: and how can I set the min x & y to (0, 0) in SwiftUI?

Comment: I tried using the .offset modifier but didn't work...

Comment: You can anchor it using the Stacks method in my answer